# What is the difference between a Cassegrain telescope and a Gregorian one? Which one is better?

Tags: observational-astronomy, telescope, observatory, newtonian-telescope, cassegrain-telescope

Of the three giant (or 'Extremely Large') new telescopes being built, the Thirty-Meter (TMT), the the Giant Magellan (GMT) and the Extremely Large Telescope (ELT), only the Magellan, from what I understand, will not feature a Cassegrain-type telescope, or some variant thereof.

Instead, the GMT will have a 'Gregorian'-style telescope, which is supposedly a predecessor of the Cassegrain....

But... What, exactly, is the difference?

Comment: Is this it? https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/21478/in-a-reflecting-telescope-cassegrain-is-there-a-difference-between-using-a-co/21479#21479

Comment: @JamesK bingo! Thanks.